# Is it possible to launch a Note popup from an Acumatica report?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I realize this is a strange request, but I've had someone ask if there's a way to edit a record's note via a hyperlink on an Acumatica report, meaning someone would be able to click on a report hyperlink (referencing the NoteID for that record) - and then open the Note editing popup screen.

Has anyone ever seen this or done anything like this?

Thanks...

Comment: Guess not.......